# How to set jQuery tabs full screen plus overflow scroll in the content

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to build a responsive web based on jQuery tabs. I want a page of this web to be completely full-screen (100% height and width), to have a fixed height for the `div.ui-tabs-nav` and to be able to scroll the content of `div.ui-tabs-panel` if it doesn't fit in the current window.

This is the basic structure of my layout:

```
<div id="queue_tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="queue_list.php?show=active">Active</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-completed">Completed</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-active">...</div> <!-- This will be automatically generated by jQuery. -->
    <div id="tabs-completed">...</div>
</div>
```

Note that although the content will be loaded through an AJAX load, I haven't included it in the following [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/carlesaraguz/9jqmcfjL/3/).

In the CSS file I have set:

```
#queue_tabs {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#queue_tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    height: 90%; /* <--- This is what I don't want. */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

As you can see, in order to expand the `div.ui-tabs-panel` I had to set the height to a particular value relative to the window height (90%), causing that `div` to be perfectly adjusted *only* under a certain condition.

Is there a way to cover all the area vertically and still allow for the overflow to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the following part:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Try to add this. You will need to ensure nothing is increasing the width of your body / html, otherwise you will face a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Indeed that's the reason why the jsFiddle wasn't working, but I already had those lines in my actual CSS. The problem is still that I have to set `height: 90%` to the `.ui-tabs-panel`, and it doesn't always look correct (specially when the browser window is really small)